# AWS SES verified emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Trying to understand something thats not clear from AWS SES emails. 
I have a simple emailer on my website that I have setup using nodemailer. 
It has 3 fields

- Name: name of user filling out form
- email: email address of user filling out email.
- Description: description filled out by user.

I'm seeing in AWS docs that I need to verify on their console the users email.

> You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains.
>   Note: This restriction applies even when your account isn't in the
>   sandbox.

This could be any number of different user email address how would I be able to verify them all I wouldn't know them.

What am I not getting here. I have verified the **To:** email which will always be the same as its coming to my domain email.

Comment: Email verification for "To" is only in sandbox environment

Comment: @JunedAhsan OP's issue is the From, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not sure as I read this "This could be any number of different user email address how would I be able to verify them all I wouldn't know them.

"

Comment: Meaning if someone is coming to my website and filling in the emailer the will be using their email. I don't know what that email would be so how would I verify it ?

Comment: Your nodemailer function isn't a magic, basically 3 informations you're taking would be used in a function to send emails , the email variable would be the recipient email and you don't need to verify it (if you're in production mode SES), however, you must have a From address something like no_reply@yourdomain.com which would be hardcoded in the function,  thats the address you need to verify in SES, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to send **from** an email address under your control (SES enforces this on a technical level, but spam filters tend to *de facto* enforce this everywhere due to things like SPF records) with a `Reply-To` header of the email address submitting the form.

Comment: What do you mean by email under my control. How can I control what email a user types into my form ?

Comment: @me-me You can't control what the user types into your form. That's why you can't use the email address they entered in the form as the email's `From` header. Your email will use `From: some-address-you-control@yourwebsite.com; Reply-To: the-address-the-user-entered@theirwebsite.com`.

Comment: Ok got it thanks for the clarification. Is there any service that allows you to use the from as the users input ? Doesn't have to be AWS. I thought AWS would allow me to do this but I guess not.

Comment: No there is no such service. Just think of all the harm you could do with such a service when you can start sending emails from any address you choose.

Comment: @me-me AWS doesn't allow it at the technical level, but even if they did, it wouldn't be worthwhile. Anti-spam techniques like SPF virtually guarantee any email you send with a spoofed `From` header goes straight into the spam folder.

Comment: @benra There are plenty of services that permit it (or you could run your own mailserver). They just tend to be black-holed into the spam folder as a result.